# How do I use a for Ioop for a Jekyll collection?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-bootstrap

I am attempting to implement some bootstrap features into an existing themed Jekyll site. I want to add some of these features in markdown so others can more easily use them.

Below is an example of how I want to add a Bootstrap accordion using a collection loop. This code is included in the _include folder:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    {% for item in site.accordion %}
        <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed accordion{{ forloop.index }}" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                {{ accordion.title }}
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body" for="accordion{{ forloop.site }}">{{ accordion.content | markdownify }}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Then, on my index page I have added:

```
{% include accordion.html %}
---
accordion: 
  - title: this is item 1
    content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  - title: this is item 2
    content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
---
```

However, the website shows this code and unformatted:

[image: accordion failing]

I can see Boostrap is already functioning but my custom variable is not. I assume there is some form of syntax error or I am missing code in a particular location (e.g. _config.yml).

How do I get Jekyll to recognize the accordion and format it in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{% for accordion in page.accordion %}`. You add the acccordion content in the front matter of the page, see code below.

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    {% for accordion in page.accordion %}
        <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed accordion{{ forloop.index }}" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                {{ accordion.title }}
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body" for="accordion{{ forloop.site }}">{{ accordion.content | markdownify }}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Within the page, move the `{% include accordion.html %}` below the front matter.

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2022-10-20 20:57:14 +0200
accordion: 
  - title: this is item 1
    content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  - title: this is item 2
    content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
---

{% include accordion.html %}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian,
Thank you very much for you help! Unfortunately there is one more issue doing this approach. Due to each accordion being labeled numerically (e.g. `flush-headingOne`, `#flush-collapseOne`, etc)  when  you open one accordion section, it will open all accordion sections. How would you prevent this?

Comment: This wasn't your original question. The index was in the original code, adjust this or your javascript.